# Correct Semantic use of CSS Properties

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

Since it is recommended not to use `table` elements for layout purposes (non-tabular data), because the special formatting applied to those elements [may change in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html#answer-84986), is it also not recommended to use CSS properties such as `text-align`, which was designed to be used on text, for `img` elements for the same semantic reason?

I have been looking through the w3c specifications and for instance, `line-height` seems to be designed for text purposes and has plenty of references in the documentation to font size, so would it be appropriate or abusive to use this property on `img` elements, simply because they are displayed as `inline`?

I can understand how the W3C idea of a [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) would use CSS to remove styling information from a page, leaving data exclusively in the HTML for content accessibility. But *where is the original rationale documentation for CSS*, and why wouldn't they use extremely abstract properties like `horizontal-align` from the get go, instead of unique alignments for each display type (e.g. `text-align: center` can be used on all `display: inline` elements such as `img` elements) ?

Comment: From what I've seen, CSS defines much formatting (accounting for many, *many* edge cases) and little semantic, if any.

Comment: @BoltClock So basically CSS isn't concerned with semantic usage in the same way that HTML and its elements such as `b` vs `strong` are?

Comment: @AlexW: The big idea is to separate content from presentation. CSS is meant to describe the presentation, not the semantic content.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail So if that was the original rationale behind CSS, why would CSS not be extremely simple and abstract starting at CSS1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. CSS is purely presentational. Some of the properties are just poorly named (text-align being a prime example, it is *designed* to align all inline children).

Comment: It seems that this is the case, but when I thought about it it seems that CSS could be *greatly* simplified to just `vertical-align` and `horizontal-align` for all elements and become very abstract, right?

Comment: I looked for documentation that contained the w3c rationale behind CSS, but didn't come up with anything concerning this.

Comment: @Alex W: Sure it could, but it'd break old browsers horribly.

Comment: The strange this is that both 'text-align' and 'vertical-align' have been in the spec since CSS1.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine, to use `text-align` in table cells, that just styling the table as you should be doing. If you want to. Just do it in CSS. Do not use `align="right"`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align
Says it applies to: block level elements, table cells and inline-blocks. So it is a use that is documented and intended. If you have inline content use this property to style its alignment.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-align Also states

> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container is aligned.

So it is not just text, but all inline content.

Comment: First of all, this is practically a comment. Second, do you have any documentation from a reputable source supporting your position?

Comment: Sorry, noticed it a little to late that I hit the wrong box. I will be editing my answer, stay tuned.